# How to add Ajax validation in a master where I have fields for other tables based on jqrelcopy?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

> > In a master page(_form) I want to save three fields
>
> 1. drop down
> 2. text box
> 3. Option list  and if a certain option from the option list is selected I need a JQrelcopy to appear and  the user can add many
>      values using JQrelcopy. The values, which are stored in JQrelcopy has
>      to be saved in some other table.
>
>    Now the problem is I want to give AJAX validation like the field
>      cannot be blank, Only alphabetical characters are allowed for the
>      fields which are inserted through JQrelcopy. I thought about creating
>      a scenario, but I can't get it right

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(  
'id'=>'symptom-form',  
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,  
  'enableClientValidation'=>true,
```

)); ?>

```
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model,"Please fill up the required field in red","");?>  
<div class="row">  
    <div class="floatleft"><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'body_system_id',   array ('id'=>'label_body_system', 'class'=>'label_name')); ?>  </div>
    <div class="floatright"><?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'body_system_id',    CHtml::listData(SystemMaster::model()->findAll("status != 'R'"),
                                    'id', 'system_name'),array('prompt' => ' ------------- Select ------------')); ?>  </div> 
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'body_system_id'); ?>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="floatleft"><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'symptom', array ('id'=>'label_symptom', 'class'=>'label_name')); ?></div>
    <div class="floatright"><?php echo $form->textField($model,'symptom',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?></div>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'symptom'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="floatleft"><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'symptom_type', array ('id'=>'symptom_type', 'class'=>'label_name')); ?></div>
    <div class="floatright"><?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model,'symptom_type',array('T'=>'TextBox','A'=>'TextArea', 'D'=>'DropDown', 'C'=>'CheckBox'), array("id"=>"r_list")); ?></div>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'symptom_type'); ?>
</div>

<div class="form" id="symptom_value">
        <?php 
            $this->widget('ext.jqrelcopy.JQRelcopy',array(

            //the id of the 'Copy' link in the view, see below.
            'id' => 'copylink',

            //add a icon image tag instead of the text
            //leave empty to disable removing
            'removeText' => '<img src="images/delete.png" /><small>Delete</small>',

            //htmlOptions of the remove link


 'removeHtmlOptions' => array('style'=>'color:red;float:left;position:absolute;'),

            //options of the plugin, see http://www.andresvidal.com/labs/relcopy.html
            'options' => array(

                //A class to attach to each copy
                'copyClass'=>'newcopy',

                // The number of allowed copies. Default: 0 is unlimited
                'limit'=>0,

                //Option to clear each copies text input fields or textarea
                'clearInputs'=>true,

                //A jQuery selector used to exclude an element and its children
                //'excludeSelector'=>'.skipcopy',

                //Additional HTML to attach at the end of each copy.
                        //'append'=>CHtml::tag('span',array('class'=>'hint'),'You can remove this line'),
                'append'=>CHtml::tag('span',array('class'=>'hint'),''),
            )
            ))
        ?>

    <!-- ---------------The given codes are used to display Symptom Values if already exists ---------------->

    <div class="topHeading" id="sli_title" ><span class="label_name">Symptom Values</span></div>

     <?php 
        if (count($symptom)>0 & $flag == 'update')
        {
            ?>
            <?php
            for ($i=0; $i<count($symptom); $i++)
            {
                ?>
              <div class="row copy">

                            <?php
                            echo CHtml::Textfield('symptom_value[]', $symptom[$i] ,array('class'=>'skipcopy','style'=>'float:left; width:150px; margin-right:5px;'));?>

                            <?php if ($i>0)
                            {
                                ?>
                                <a href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().remove(); return false;" style="color: red;"><img src="images/delete.png"  align="" /><small>Delete</small></a>
                                                                <span class="hint"></span>

                            <?php 
                            } 

                            ?>

             </div> <?php  
            }
            ?>   
            <?php
        }
        else
        {
        ?>            
                        <div class="row copy">
                            <?php $i=0;
                            echo CHtml::Textfield('symptom_value[]', " " ,array('class'=>'skipcopy'));?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <?php //echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'body_system_id', CHtml::listData(SystemMaster::model()->findAll("status != 'R'"),
                                  //'id', 'system_name'),array('prompt' => ' ------------- Select ------------')); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <?php if ($i>0)
                        {
                            ?>
                            <div class="floatright"><a href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().remove(); return false;" style="color: red;"><img src="images/delete.png"  align="" /><small>Delete</small></a>
                                                            <span class="hint"></span>
                                                            </div>
                        <?php 
                        } $i++;

                        ?>


                        </div>
            <?php
        }
         ?>
            <div class="row"><div><a id="copylink" href="#" rel=".copy"> <img src="images/add.png" align="" /><small>Add Another</small></a></div></div>

                </div>

        <!-- Symptom Values -->
            <div class="row buttons">
    <div class="floatright"><?php //echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Save' : 'Save', array ('onClick'=>'validate()')); ?></div>
            <div class="floatright"><?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Save' : 'Save'); ?></div>
</div>
    <div class="floatright"><?php //echo CHtml::hiddenfield('Sys_val',' ' ,array ('id'=>'Sys_val')); ?></div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div><!-- form -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    check();

    function check()
    {

            if ($("#Symptom_symptom_type_2").prop('checked') || ($("#Symptom_symptom_type_3").prop('checked')))
            {
                $("#symptom_value").show()
            }
            else 
            {
                $("#symptom_value").hide()
            }
    }

});
if ($("#Symptom_symptom_type_2").click(function()
{
    $("#symptom_value").show()
}));

if ($("#Symptom_symptom_type_3").click(function()
{
    $("#symptom_value").show()
}));

if ($("#Symptom_symptom_type_1").click(function()
{
    $("#symptom_value").hide()
}));

if ($("#Symptom_symptom_type_0").click(function()
{
    $("#symptom_value").hide()
}));
function validate()
   {
   var body_system = document.getElementById("Symptom_body_system_id").value
   var symptom = document.getElementById("Symptom_symptom").value


   if ($("#Symptom_symptom_type_0").attr("checked") != "checked" 
      && $("#Symptom_symptom_type_1").attr("checked") != "checked" 
      && $("#Symptom_symptom_type_2").attr("checked") != "checked" 
      && $("#Symptom_symptom_type_3").attr("checked") != "checked"
      || (body_system == "" || symptom == ""))
   {
        alert("Please enter all the mandatory fields Body System , Symptom  and Symptom Type");
   }
   return;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: How to attach a file? any options?

Comment: just copy your code to the question, (edit it). Use proper formatting, read the [editing help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Well formatted questions are easier to read, easier to understand, giving you faster answers.

Comment: I did my best to edit the code, sorry for the delay, (thanks bool.dev)

Comment: ok, that's better, but one thing, you need not put your question itself in blockquote, i.e using the `>` . the general convention here, is to use `>` when quoting some resource, like say quoting from some documentation. but ofcourse you are free to do as you wish. i'll look at the edit and try to answer, in time.